# Linux Script to find desired output related to file permissions

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

```
ls -alR | awk '{k=0; for(i=0;i<=8;i++) k+=((substr($1, i+2, 1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i)); if(k)printf("%o", k); print}' | cut -c 1-3 | sort -n | uniq -c | cut -d " " -f 6-8
```

Output :

```
 1 .:
./.
 1 ./b
 2 ./D
 1 ./M
 2 ./o
 1 ./P
 1 ./T
tot
 1 ./V
 1 1./
 1 4./
 2 10.
 1 40.
 2 500

20 640
644

700
78 755
 3 764
77 775
 6 777
```

Desired Output: Only count of files grouped by file permissions.
e.g.

```
2 774
3 664
```

Comment: See [ParsingLs](mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for why doing that is a bad idea. Then perhaps try using something like `find . -printf %m\\n | sort | uniq -c`?

Comment: You can include newlines in a single-quoted string in the shell, and putting some newlines in your awk script would make it much easier for us to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/dir -printf '%m\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

`%m` stands for file permissions in the `-printf`'s format. `\n` stands for a newline.